# How to create Date from json format of TimeStamp in Java

Tags: java, datetime, timestamp

I have json format of TimeStamp:

```
{
    "time":1443435459000,
    "javaClass":"java.sql.Timestamp"
}
```

My question is how to create Date from it.

Comment: Please search StackOverflow before posting. This issue has been asked and answered many times already.

Comment: No such thing as a "JSON format of Timestamp". JSON offers [very few data types](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Json), and none are date-time related.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it by this:

```
Calendar start = Calendar.getInstance();
start.setTimeInMillis( timeStampValue.getTime() );

Date myDate = start.getTime();
```